# T-SQL Using Lead () function, but doesn't allow it in GROUP BY or in UPDATE

Tags: t-sql, window-functions, lag, issue-tracking, lead

I am trying to insert some data from a different DB.

And while doing my "insert", I am creating **ExpirationDate**, based on  **EffectiveDate** column.

My problem - I am using lead() function for that purpose.

And if I leave that expression in my SELECT clause, then I receive an error - that it must be also used in GROUP BY clause.
If adding an expression in GROUP BY - the following error occurs -
"**Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses**"

So, I was trying to use UPDATE instead and of course, still the same error -

Please, advice - how? where? can I use my lead() for creating [ExpirationDate] so it wouldn't given me that "Windowed function" error...
If I can use other function or rebuild my query differently - would be also appreciated

Please, see my query below:

(My only problem that gives me error is the one, that commented out, after SELECT 
**-- DateAdd(....**

Or -  after the UPDATE - **SET cmp.[ExpirationDate] = DateAdd(....**  )

```
     USE [WH];
     DELETE FROM [Fact].[ClientMedicalProfile];

     INSERT INTO [Fact].[ClientMedicalProfile] (
                 [DBID]
                ,[EHRClientFK]
                ,[EHRProgramFK]
                ,[MedicalConditionFK]
                ,[EffectiveDate]
                ,[ExpirationDate]

                                              )
     SELECT 
           p.[clientmedicalprofile_id]
          ,ec.[WHID]
          ,Max(ISNULL(epi.[EHRProgramFK], -1)) AS [EHRProgramFK]
          ,c.[medicalcondition_id]
          ,p.[effective_date]
      --  ,DateAdd(day, -1, lead (p.[effective_date], 1, '2050-12-31') OVER (partition by p. 
                    [client_id], c.[medicalcondition_id] Order By p.[effective_date])) 
                                                                                  AS [ExpirationDate]
          ,'2050-12-31' AS [ExpirationDate]

   FROM 
        [WH-SSIS].[Integration].[Staged_CredibleClientMedicalProfileMedicalCondition] c
        INNER JOIN [WH-SSIS].[Integration].[Staged_CredibleClientMedicalProfile] p ON 
                             c.[ClientMedicalProfile_id] = p.[ClientMedicalProfile_id]
        LEFT JOIN [Fact].[EHREpisode] epi ON (p.[effective_date] 
                  BETWEEN epi.[AdmissionDate] AND epi.[DischargeDate] and epi.[DBCode] = 'CRED')
        INNER JOIN [Dimension].[EHRClient] ec ON p.[client_id] = ec.[DBID] AND ec.[DBCode] = 'CRED'


    WHERE
         (p.[effective_date] IS NOT NULL)


    GROUP BY
             p.[clientmedicalprofile_id]
            ,ec.[WHID]
            ,c.[medicalcondition_id]
            ,p.[effective_date]

  UPDATE cmp
    SET cmp.[ExpirationDate] = DateAdd(day, -1, lead (p.[effective_date], 1, '2050-12-31') 
        OVER (partition by p.[client_id], c.[medicalcondition_id] Order By p.[effective_date]))
 FROM 
     [Fact].[ClientMedicalProfile] cmp
     INNER JOIN [WH-SSIS].[Integration].[Staged_CredibleClientMedicalProfileMedicalCondition] c 
                ON cmp.[DBID] = c.[clientmedicalprofile_id]
      INNER JOIN [WH-SSIS].[Integration].[Staged_CredibleClientMedicalProfile] p ON 
                  c.[ClientMedicalProfile_id] = p.[ClientMedicalProfile_id]
```

Comment: you are not allow to do that. use a CTE or derived table

Comment: @Squirrel What is CTE?

Comment: `Common Table Expression` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Squirrel  I am not exactly sure how to use it  I will create more simplified post with question